# PYTHON: I want to class all of my txt file data but everytime i try to it says that i am missing the data required

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object

This is the code I have designed as of now.

```
import sys                 #so that later on I can exit easily

CoinCountData = open("CoinCountData.txt","r")
class Volunteer:
 def __init__(self,name,coin_type,weight_of_bag,TrueCount):
    self.name = (name)
    self.coin_type = (coin_type)                            #a function allowing me to class the data
    self.weight_of_bag = (weight_of_bag)
    self.TrueCount = (TrueCount)
```

I also have a little test part of data which is an attempt to make the second row of my txt file into a class

```
volunteer1 = Volunteer(CoinCountData.readlines()[1])
```

---

however, I am prompted with the following message.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\CW\!Coincount\coincount.py", line 14, in <module>
    volunteer1 = Volunteer(CoinCountData.readlines()[1])
TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'coin_type', 'weight_of_bag', and 'TrueCount'
```

I do not understand how to actually class this data. It seems that it thinks that the entire thing is a name, I figured out that that is what the problem is by changing the code for an experiment:

```
import sys                 #so that later on I can exit easily

CoinCountData = open("CoinCountData.txt","r") 

class Volunteer:

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = (name)


volunteer1 = Volunteer(CoinCountData.readlines()[1])

print(volunteer1.name)
```

When I ran the program it printed the entire line (*Malcolm,1p,3356.00,Y*)

Just for context, this is for my project for making a coin counter, the data given to me for the coin counting is as follows:

```
Abena,5p,325.00,Y
Malcolm,1p,3356.00,Y
Jane,£2,120.00,Y
Andy,£1,166.25,N
Sandip,50p,160.00,Y
Liz,20p,250.00,Y
Andy,20p,250.00,Y
Andy,50p,160.00,Y
Jane,£1,183.75,N
Liz,£,179.0,N
Liz,50p,170.0,N
Jane,50p,160.0,Y
Sandip,£1,183.0,N
Jane,£2,132.0,N
Abena,1p,3356.0,N
Andy,2p,250.0,N
Abena,£1,175.0,Y
Malcolm,50p,160.0,Y
Malcolm,£2,175.0,N
Malcolm,£1,175.0,Y
Malcolm,1p,356.0,Y
Liz,20p,250.0,Y
Jane,£2,120.0,Y
Jane,50p,160.0,Y
Andy,£1,175.0,Y
Abena,1p,359.56,N
Andy,5p,328.5,N
Andy,£2,108.0,N
Malcolm,£2,12.0,N
```

The data is listed vertically so it shows `Abena,5p,325.00,Y` and then below is `Malcolm,1p,3356.00,Y` etc

I understand the issue that the commas within the text file do not work as actual legitimate commas within python, I am not allowed to change the actual text file either so please let me know how I can make a full class which inputs all variables.

Comment: Hi SixCray - welcome to Stack Overflow!  This post seems to be one related to a homework - though it's not required, it might be helpful to say as much to help get more useful answers. Having said that - you've done a decent job of following the [guidelines for posting questions about homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/334823#334823) - ie, you've posted sample code showing what you've tried, and you've been fairly clear about what parts you still don't understand. So congrats on making a good first post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be iterating over the open file and splitting each line to provide the required parameters:

```py
class Volunteer:
 def __init__(self,name,coin_type,weight_of_bag,TrueCount):
    self.name = name
    self.coin_type = coin_type        #a function allowing me to class the data
    self.weight_of_bag = weight_of_bag
    self.TrueCount = TrueCount

with open("CoinCountData.txt","r") as CoinCountData:
    volunteers = []
    for line in CoinCountData 
        volunteers.append(Volunteer(*line.strip().split(',')))
```

Comment: thank you so much, i pasted in this to see what it does but i have no idea what it actually does, can you please explain the code that you input on this and could you also explain how i am meant to find the data on here, your response may be long but i just need to understand what the function you made does and how to access the data it is storing, if there is an issue with you explaining this on the comments then please take my discord '6.#5898' and send me a message explaining it.

Comment: The code in this answer is not much different to your post. The instances are stored in the list ‘volunteers’. Just add some ‘print()’s to see what is going on.

Comment: when i type print(volunteers) it just says '[<__main__.Volunteer object at 0x00000223B6E4EF10>, <__main__.Volunteer object at 0x00000223B6E4EA90>, <__main__.Volunteer object at 0x00000223B6E4E7F0>, <__main__.Volunteer object at 0x00000223B6E4E3D0>, <__main__.Volunteer object at 0x00000223B6E52760>, <__main__.Volunteer object at 0x00000223B6FA0A3' , how do i actually access the information???

Comment: Don’t you know about lists? Try ‘print(volunteer[0].name)’

Comment: honestly, I know barely anything about python, I'm in my second year of computer science GCSE and we have never gone through it, so yes I do not know about lists, but thanks a bunch man

Comment: Hey, I'm pleased to try to help anyone out here, but when you quote code I have written for you verbatim, I would expect a passing reference to the source. Can you do that, or do I have to edit your latest question for you?

Answer (score 1):

The error message you get is pretty straightforward.

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\CW!Coincount\coincount.py", line 14, in volunteer1 = Volunteer(CoinCountData.readlines()[1]) TypeError: init() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'coin_type', 'weight_of_bag', and 'TrueCount

It basically tells you that 3 parameters are missing when you're instanciating your `Volunteer` object : `coin_type`, `weight_of_bag` and `TrueCount` (which by the way should be named `true_count` to be consistent with the rest of your parameters).

Now, if you take a closer look at your code :

```py
class Volunteer:
 def __init__(self,name,coin_type,weight_of_bag,TrueCount):
     ...
```

You see here that when instanciating your `Volunteer` object, you need to give it 4 parameters : `name`, `coin_type`, `weight_of_bag` and `TrueCount` (`self` does not count as a parameter you need to provide).

Now, when you're instanciating your object, you do as follow :

```py
volunteer1 = Volunteer(CoinCountData.readlines()[1])
```

You only give one parameter (that is, `name`). You also need to provide values for `coin_type`, `weight_of_bag` and `TrueCount` parameters.

It should look like something like that:

```py
volunteer1 = Volunteer(CoinCountData.readlines()[1], "some coin type", 42, 14)
```

where `name` has the value of `CoinCountData.readlines()[1]`, `coin_type` has the value `some coin type` and so on.

### Readlines

I think you'll go into some more issues afterward, as your usage of `readlines()` seems incorrect in your case.

The `readlines()` method returns a list containing each line in your file (https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html?highlight=readlines#distutils.text_file.TextFile.readlines).

So you will need a loop somewhere to loop over each line if you want to do it the way you've started.

### CSV

The data file you're working with is a CSV (comma separated values). It means each line is a data entry, with each value separated by a comma.

You should have a look on the Python doc on how to read an CSV file : https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

`readlines` returns a list of strings, each of the strings representing a line from the file.

You need to split the lines into their components, which you could do using

```
CoinCountData.readlines()[1].split(',')
```

You could then use argument unpacking to create an instance of the Volunteer class:

```
Volunterr(*CoinCountData.readlines()[1].split(','))
```

Note the asterisk (*).

Comment: thanks so much! I would like the ask what the reason for the asterisk is though, like what does it actually do

Comment: Given a list `l =[1, 5, 7]` and a function `def foo(a, b, c)`, if you call it like `foo(l)`, the list will be put into `a`, while `b` and `c`  will remain unspecified. If you call it like `foo(*l)`, the list gets split into its components which are then used to call the function.